# Assorting elements in a list into a list of lists of specific lengths

Tags: python, list, sorting, split

Hey guys I'm using python and I was just wondering how we can make combinations of lists of specific lengths from an original list of elements? For example, I have an original list `["2H", "AH", "KH", "QH", "JH", "0H", "9H"]`, is there any way for me to create a final list where ALL of the new assorted lists of specific lengths (`3` to `5`) are contained?

Basically from the original list above, I want a returned list as shown below:

```
[['9H', '0H', 'JH'], ['0H', 'JH', 'QH'], ['JH', 'QH', 'KH'], ['QH', 'KH', 'AH'], 
['KH', 'AH', '2H'], ['9H', '0H', 'JH', 'QH'], ['0H', 'JH', 'QH', 'KH'], 
['JH', 'QH', 'KH', 'AH'], ['QH', 'KH', 'AH', '2H'], ['9H', '0H', 'JH', 'QH', 'KH'], 
['0H', 'JH', 'QH', 'KH', 'AH'], ['JH', 'QH', 'KH', 'AH', '2H']]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> from itertools import islice, chain
>>> L = ["2H", "AH", "KH", "QH", "JH", "0H", "9H"]
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(
        zip(*[islice(reversed(L),i,None) for i in range(j)])
        for j in range(3,6)))
[('9H', '0H', 'JH'), ('0H', 'JH', 'QH'), ('JH', 'QH', 'KH'), ('QH', 'KH', 'AH'), 
 ('KH', 'AH', '2H'), ('9H', '0H', 'JH', 'QH'), ('0H', 'JH', 'QH', 'KH'), 
 ('JH', 'QH', 'KH', 'AH'), ('QH', 'KH', 'AH', '2H'), ('9H', '0H', 'JH', 'QH', 'KH'),
 ('0H', 'JH', 'QH', 'KH', 'AH'), ('JH', 'QH', 'KH', 'AH', '2H')]
```

**Explanation**

This solution builds on the use of `zip`.

```
>>> zip(L,L)
[('2H', '2H'), ('AH', 'AH'), ('KH', 'KH'), ('QH', 'QH'), ('JH', 'JH'), ('0H', '0H'), ('9H', '9H')]
```

This shows an example of how `zip` works, by taking an item from each of its paramters together.

```
>>> zip(L,L[1:])
[('2H', 'AH'), ('AH', 'KH'), ('KH', 'QH'), ('QH', 'JH'), ('JH', '0H'), ('0H', '9H')]
```

By starting at the 1st item of the same list as the second paramater you can get every 2 items.

```
>>> zip(L,L[1:],L[2:])
[('2H', 'AH', 'KH'), ('AH', 'KH', 'QH'), ('KH', 'QH', 'JH'), ('QH', 'JH', '0H'), ('JH', '0H', '9H')]
```

Same for every 3 items.

```
>>> zip(*[L[i:] for i in range(3)])
[('2H', 'AH', 'KH'), ('AH', 'KH', 'QH'), ('KH', 'QH', 'JH'), ('QH', 'JH', '0H'), ('JH', '0H', '9H')]
```

To do this automatically you can use the `*` (splat) to get the arguments of `zip` from a list comprehension.

In the example, the results come in reverse, so `reversed` gives a reverse iterator through the list. To slice an iterator, `islice` from itertools must be used. `islice` takes the iterable followed by the index to start the slice and the index to end it. `None` can be used to go all the way to the end of the iterable.

```
>>> zip(*[islice(reversed(L),i,None) for i in range(3)])
[('9H', '0H', 'JH'), ('0H', 'JH', 'QH'), ('JH', 'QH', 'KH'), ('QH', 'KH', 'AH'), ('KH', 'AH', '2H')]
```

So that gives all the results for every 3 items. Now every 4 and 5 items are needed so this operation is performed for `range(3)`, `range(4)` and `range(5)`.

```
(zip(*[islice(reversed(L),i,None) for i in range(j)]) for j in range(3,6))
```

This would give a generator with a list for each of `3`, `4`, and `5` but they need to be all one list. They can be chained together with`chain.from_iterable` with the result being converted to a `list`.

Comment: Just wondering do you have any way I can contact you? Facebook?

Comment: @AdhyKarina Hahaha I don't know what to say you are welcome :D Contact me for what reason? I don't need anything thanks is good enough :)

Comment: For the reason so you could be someone I can ask for help whenever I need. :P Can you please explain me in simple plain english how the above code did what it did? Thanks!

Comment: @AdhyKarina I already have enough work helping my own friends :D I added an explanation, i thought it was better to show each step by example than just with plain English.

Answer (score -1):

Use [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
import itertools

original = ["2H", "AH", "KH", "QH", "JH", "0H", "9H"]

result = itertools.chain()
for size in range(3, 6):
    curr_subsets = itertools.combinations(original, size)
    result = itertools.chain(result, curr_subsets)

result_as_list = list(result)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It does not produce the correct output as listed in the question.

Comment: It may not produce the same output but it certainly produces "combinations of lists of specific lengths from an original list of elements". It is up to the OP to specify exactly what they want. If the ordering is relevant, it certainly isn't stated anywhere in the post.

Comment: The use of the word 'combinations' may be misleading, he just wants every 3, 4 and 5 items in the list. He did specify exactly what he wanted in his desired output listed above.

Comment: No, he should an acceptable output, but did not specify that the given output was exactly what he needed. Anyhow, the problem is not hard and the other solution is just fine.